# Ember delay controller until authentication completes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a situation where I need to get some properties on the session, but I haven't found a successful solution to delay the loading of the route after a successful login.

So here's the deal - when the user logs in, they get sent to the phone-numbers route. The this.get('session.currentUser') on the application controller is not set yet.

When I go to a different route and then come back, it is set correctly. If I'm on the phone-numbers route after login and then refresh the page, the phone-numbers load correctly because of the deferReadiness and advanceReadiness in the initializer. I can't deferReadiness before a login because the app is already loaded and ready.

The only part that's missing is that after the user logs in, it should load the numbers in the `routes/phone-numbers.js`, the last block of code pasted below. However, the `myStoreId` is not loaded because the `session.currentUser` is not set yet.

I've tried so many things to get this working and am looking for some ideas on this final part. It's so close to working, but just missing one little piece.

```
// initializers/current-user.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import Session from 'simple-auth/session';

export default {
  name: 'current-user',
  before: 'simple-auth',

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    Session.reopen({
      setCurrentUser: function() {
        let appController = container.lookup("controller:application");

        // don't know how to check if the app is already ready
        try{
          application.deferReadiness();
          console.log('deferred');
        }catch(e){}

        if(this.get('isAuthenticated')) {
          console.log('running the isAuthenticated obs');

          let store = container.lookup('store:main');
          let _this = this;

          return store.find('user', 'me').then((user) => {
            // set the current user to be used on the session object
            this.set('currentUser', user);
          }).then(function(){
            // set the store for the current user
            store.find('store', {user: _this.get('currentUser.id')}).then(function(data) {
              _this.set('myStore', data.get('firstObject'));
              application.advanceReadiness();
            });
          })
        }
      }.observes('isAuthenticated')
    });
  }
};

// controllers/application.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  myStore: Ember.computed(function(){
    // return the store object that is associated with the current user
    if(this.get('session.isAuthenticated')){
      if(this.get('session.myStore')){
        return this.get('session.myStore');
      }else{
        console.log(this.get('session.currentUser'));
        // this is where the problem is. The session.currentUser is not populated yet.

        this.get('store').find('store', {user: this.get('session.currentUser.id')}).then(function(data) {
          this.get('session').set('myStore', data.get('firstObject'));
          return this.get('session.myStore');
        });
      }
    }
  }),
});


// routes/phone-numbers.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    let myStoreId = this.controllerFor('application').get('myStore.id');

    if(!myStoreId){
      console.log(this.get('session.currentUser'));
      // there is no currentUser set on the session after login
    }else{
      this.store.find('store-phone-number', {'store': myStoreId}).then(function(numbers){
        controller.set('numbers', numbers);
      });
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Promises:

```
// controllers/application.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  myStore: Ember.computed('session.currentUser', function(){
    // return the store object that is associated with the current user
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(resolve => {
      if(this.get('session.isAuthenticated')){
        if(this.get('session.myStore')){
          resolve(this.get('session.myStore'));
        } else {
          console.log(this.get('session.currentUser'));
          // this is where the problem is. The session.currentUser is not populated yet.

          this.get('store').find('store', {user: this.get('session.currentUser.id')}).then(function(data) {
            this.get('session').set('myStore', data.get('firstObject'));
            resolve(this.get('session.myStore'));
          });
        }
      }
    });
  })
});


// routes/phone-numbers.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    let myStoreId = this.controllerFor('application').get('myStore').then(myStore => {
      let myStoreId = myStore.get('id');
      if(!myStoreId){
        console.log(this.get('session.currentUser'));
        // there is no currentUser set on the session after login
      } else {
        this.store.find('store-phone-number', {'store': myStoreId}).then(function(numbers){
          controller.set('numbers', numbers);
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, I'll play around with this. With this example the `this.get('session.currentUser.id')` inside the promise still isn't available when logging in, and also on refresh/routing it isn't defined and gives an error

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's suggestion of playing around with the promises got me to the solution. Essentially I needed to return a promise if the myStore hadn't been set yet and also had to account for that in the first route after login.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  myStore: Ember.computed(function(){
    // return the store object that is associated with the current user
    if(this.get('session.isAuthenticated')){
      if(this.get('session.myStore')){
        return this.get('session.myStore');
      }else{
        return new Promise(resolve =>{
          this.get('session').setCurrentUser().then(data => {
            this.get('store').find('store', {user: this.get('session.currentUser.id')}).then(data => {
              this.get('session').set('myStore', data.get('firstObject'));
              resolve(this.get('session.myStore'));
            });
          });
        })
      }
    }
  }),
});

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setNumbers: function(controller, id){
    this.store.find('store-phone-number', {'store': id}).then(numbers => {
      controller.set('numbers', numbers);
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);

    if(this.controllerFor('application').get('myStore.id')){
      let myStoreId = this.controllerFor('application').get('myStore.id')
      this.setNumbers(controller, myStoreId);
    }else{
      let myStore = this.controllerFor('application').get('myStore').then(data => {
        this.setNumbers(controller, data.id);
      });
    }
  },
});
```